# Create dynamic object for angular chart

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

I want to create dynamic an Object like this for using it with Angular Chart.

```
[{
id:0,
name: 'WI',
type: 'NI',
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
data: [[28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]]
}];
```

I created a class named LineChart :

```
public class LineChart 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }
    public int[] Data { get; set; }
}


public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetInformation()
    {
        try
        {

            string[] labels = new string[7] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"};
            int[] numbers = new int[] { 28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90 };

            List<LineChart> line = new List<LineChart>();
            LineChart linechart = new LineChart();
            linechart.Id = 0;
            linechart.Name = "WI";
            linechart.Data = numbers;
            linechart.Labels = labels;

            line.Add(linechart);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, line);
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable,
                "The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again at a later time.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e);
        }
    }
```

The problem is with the Data, I have it in a form like this : [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90] why there should be double brackets between like 
[[28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]].

What is the best way to get your data between double brackets? Like [[ and here goes my data ]]

Comment: if you want double `[[` that means it would be an array in another array? What you declared for Data is an array of int `public int[] Data { get; set; }`

Comment: What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why would you need an array inside another if Data is supposed to hold your integers like it actually does?

Comment: Because for angular chart's the data should be hold like [ [ data ] ] otherwise the functionalities are not working. Like the hovering etc.

Comment: take a look at the answer I posted and let me know if it fits your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from comments received here's how I would do it:

```
string[] labels = new string[7] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"};
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90 };
        var arrayHolder = new List<int[]>();
        arrayHolder.Add(numbers);

        List<LineChart> line = new List<LineChart>();
        LineChart linechart = new LineChart();
        linechart.Id = 0;
        linechart.Name = "WI";
        linechart.Data = arrayHolder.ToArray();
        linechart.Labels = labels;
```